# PHP Include not working? I am using the file path to open on chrome

Tags: php, navbar, php-include

I want to add a  nav bar using php include, but I have it in a loop in the navBar.php file:

```
<?php
$Links = array("index.php", "page1.php", "page2.php");
$Text = array("Home", "page1", "page2");
$ReqPage = (explode('/', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']));
echo $ReqPage[2];
$Nav="\r\n<div id=\"navwrapper\">\r\n
          <div id=\"nav\">\r\n
          <ul id=\"navstuff\">\r\n";
$j = 0;
foreach($Links as $ALink){
    if ($ALink == $ReqPage){
        $Nav .= "<li class=\"selected\"><a href=\"#\">";
    } else{
        $Nav .= "<li><a href=\"$ALink\">";
    }
    $Nav .= "$Text[$j]</a></li>\r\n";
    $j++;
}
$Nav .= "</ul>\r\n
        </div>\r\n
        </div>\r\n";
echo $Nav;
?>
```

I have it in my index.php file as `<?php include("navBar.php"); ?>`. It is not showing anything. Is it because I am not running off of a server? Currently I am opening the file by just typing in the file path into Chrome. Do I have to use a server for this? Also, If I have to use a server, what are some good ones for my computer (I don't want to pay money for large external servers)?

Comment: do u want to include this file in index.php file?

Comment: What did you mean _I am not running off of a server?_

Comment: haha, you need to run a server to interpret and run your php code. You can't just open the file in a browser.

Comment: If you can see the php code in browser then your url will be like `file:///your-path-to-file.php` but it should be `http://localhost/your-path-to-file.php` so I hope u r using xampp, lamp or mamp stack for it....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you need to run server software that has php functionality installed.

I would recommend Apache+PHP which will run on your local machine and won't cost you anything.

Search for an installation guide for beginners.

EDIT:

Actually all you need is PHP. It has an [inbuilt web server](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php) which would be perfect for testing on a local machine.

Comment: Thanks! Also, how is this compared to WAMP?